# why vector pointer's memory automatically cleared

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

BS: I've tested, the question below is VS2010 specific, in my test on Mingw, vector memory is leak,  the
    printf("%d\n", testV->size());
gives me '10', which shows it's a leak.

In codes like below:

```
class Test{
public:
    std::vector<int> *num;
    int *n;
};

Test *t = new Test();
t->num = new std::vector<int>;
t->num->assign(10,10);
t->n = new int[20];
t->n[0] = 12345;
int *testN = t->n;
std::vector<int> *testV;

testV = t->num;
delete t;

//I can print n's memory
printf("%d\n", testN[0]);  //get 12345, so memory leaked here.

//I can't print num's memory; its size is 0. in release version, it's negative number.
printf("%d\n", testV->size());
```

After deleting t, I see that the memory num points to is cleared, in my VS10 environment, I could see its memory cleaned to 'ee fe ee fe....'.
But the memory of n stays the same.

In my opinion, all memory comes from keyword new, should be freed by delete, well, here the num (vector) is
not 'delete'd, but rather is cleared automatically.

I want to know how vector pointer is different from other ones?

Comment: the pointer to vector is not different. You still have to call `delete` on this newed pointer, despite whatever your debugger might lead you to believe.

Comment: your test doesn't fill vector with any initial values so of course `testV->size()` will be 0.

Comment: Sorry, I filled it now, it's (the size) a negative number, so I guess the memory is automatically cleaned? I'm just confused why it's not 10 anymore, if this memory leaked, it should stay the same?

Comment: Does `vector<int>::size_type` print correctly as an `int`? What happens if you use `cout` instead?

Comment: I just tried your example and I can't reproduce the behavior that you're describing [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=db04d046a9370430f035f80e6eb12998-c24d8bb04c821c1cef37a53399b6efc2).

Comment: Yes, on Mingw, I get different things too, I guess vs did something to 'save my fault'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debug runtime will overwrite memory it deletes with a marker like eefe to detect bugs like use-after-free. A release build will not do this.

You are probably just misreading the debug output. Both the vector* and the int* memory will still be around. The debugger is probably just trying to be smarter about vectors.

Comment: I can print testN[0], so test->n is leaked.
But testV.size() is a negative number, rather than 20, so I think this indicates that test->num's memory is cleared?

Comment: Yes, it's a compiler specific thing. On Mingw, things are different. So I can't rely on this feature.

Comment: @RobertBean being able to `printf` something does not mean it is leaked (or that it hasn't been deleted. It just means you are writing broken code which tries to access memory after it has been deleted

Comment: You are right... But this is the only way I came up of testing if a memory is leaked... Or is it just we can only technically say it's leaked without any way to prove it? Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

Only `t`'s memory is released, what the members `num` and `n` point to is leaked memory.

Your test is wrong, because you can't inspect `t` after you've deleted it, and there are no other ways to access those members (ergo the leak).

Comment: I've just edited my question, I do can inspect the memory. I originally do it by memory-spying tool, in vs2010, alt+6 do it.
Now, in my new code, I inspect them by another pointer. They behave like I described in VS2010

Comment: Since `t->n` isn't being freed, the memory allocation will remain after you have freed `t`, yes. The pointer within `t` is overwritten (in a debug build). Using ANYTHING within `t` after it has been freed is "undefined behaviour", which means it may not work as you expect it to - no matter what you expect.

Comment: I also think t->num(the vector pointer) should cause a leak, but in my test, it seemes not a leak, cause the leaked memory got cleared up. (I get this conclusion for testV.size() is a negative number, rather than 10 which is what I assign to the vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this correctly, you need to `delete [] t->n;` and `delete t->num;` before you do `delete t;` - but a more correct way, using object orientation "correctly", would be to let `t`'s constructor and destructor handle the memory allocation and freeing of `n` and `num` - with that, automatically, the memory is managed correctly for the class itself.

I would also point out that it's rarely right to use a pointer to a `std::vector` - the vector itself doesn't take up that much space, so you probably should use `std::vector<int> num;` instead of a pointer to it. This would also mean that `num` is automatically destroyed in the destructor without any additional code required.